# Adding a custom attribute in product detail page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-view

I want to add a custom "text_area" attribute after the short description in products page

attribute_id : 1109, attribute_code : rerestock

so I put the code in view.phtml

```
<div class="rerestock">
     <?php echo $_product->getrerestock(); ?> 
</div>
```

but I also want to put

```
 <?php echo 'RESTOCK INFORMATION ?>
```

only 'rerestock' attribute is filled with some information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attribute's First Letter should be capital to get its value..

Try below code:

`<?php echo $_product->getRerestock(); ?>`

OR

```
<?php echo $_product->getData("rerestock"); ?>
```

Hope it helps.